# Laravel json or query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, jsonb

This is my json in **attribute column**

```
first row entry
[{
    "id": 1,
    "img": "img-1.jpg",
    "name": "Name 1"
}]
second row entry
[{
    "id": 2,
    "img": "img-2.jpg",
    "name": "Name 2"
}]
third row entry
[{
    "id": 3,
    "img": "img-3",
    "name": "Name 2"
}]
```

I want to create laravel json query in which I can select the json data where `(id=3 or id=2 and name="Name 2")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here, how to make json queries
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses

Just the same as other queries.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->where(function($query){
    $query->where('column->id', 2)
        ->orWhere('column->id', 3)
})
->where('column->name', "Name 2")
->get();
```

For unknown count of parameters build query as it described in documentation.

```
$usersQuery = DB::table('users')
->where(function($query){
    $query->where('column->id', 2)
        ->orWhere('column->id', 3)
})
->where('column->name', "Name 2");
foreach(...){
    $usersQuery->where('column->name', "Name xxx");
}
$users = $usersQuery->get();
```

Comment: if i don't know how many id and names are in request json then what should I do

Comment: You should program it:) Use loop and combination of queries, will update answer